# The value of method argument changes after the method is called

Tags: c#, mono

Perhaps I'm too tired and I'm hallucinating or maybe there's actually something wrong with C# + Mono!!

I was testing and debugging in [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com) while I came across `SetPropertyValue` method of class `JsonSerializerInternalReader`. This method calls another private method named `CalculatePropertyDetails`. One of the arguments passed to `CalculatePropertyDetails` is called `reader` of type `JsonReader`. This object has got value before it is passed to the `CalculatePropertyDetails` method and it's null afterwards!!

I know it sounds so stupid and believe me I'm not naive, but what could have happened in order to see such strange behavior? Can anyone come up with a rational explanation? All I know is that this project is not multi-threaded and the results are reproducible.

The only proof I've got is the two entries on top of my call stack:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CalculatePropertyDetails (property={Id}, propertyConverter={JsonRpcTest.ObjectIdConverter}, containerContract={Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract}, containerProperty=(null), reader=(null), target=(null), useExistingValue=false, currentValue=(null), propertyContract=(null), gottenCurrentValue=false) in Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:792
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue (property={Id}, propertyConverter={JsonRpcTest.ObjectIdConverter}, containerContract={Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract}, containerProperty=(null), reader={Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader}, target={JsonRpcTest.E}) in Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:750
```

Look for `reader` argument.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Mono 3.2.3 and Monodevelop 4.1.7 and project is developed using `Mono / .Net 4.5`.

**[UPDATE]**

Here's a part of code from where `SetPropertyValue` is defined and where `CalculatePropertyDetails` is called:

```
private bool SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, object target)
{
    object currentValue;
    bool useExistingValue;
    JsonContract propertyContract;
    bool gottenCurrentValue;

    if (CalculatePropertyDetails(property, ref propertyConverter, containerContract, containerProperty, reader, target, out useExistingValue, out currentValue, out propertyContract, out gottenCurrentValue))
        return false;
```

Comment: Could it be just a quirk of the debugger?

Comment: It could but does it really matter if it happens only in debug mode or in actual run time? To me it stops me from debugging the rest of the code because an exception is thrown due to this problem.

Comment: What I'm saying, maybe the debugger doesn't show you what's actually happening.

Comment: As I said: due to the object being null; an exception was thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be GC collects your object while execution? I saw such behaviour in one of the mono forks. You can check it - simple create the public field with reader object in the parent class for SetPropertyValue and set it with actual reader. In case of GC issue it should not be nulled after this.

Comment: GC can't collection something that's still referenced.

Comment: @gleb.kudr You are right. It sounds like a GC problem. I added a dummy field to the class and saved the `reader` object in it. Now the method argument is not null anymore! Thanks.

Comment: @svick actually it can in some cases. It is a weird behaviour of Mono GC and I remember some explanatory topics about it (written by Miguel de Icaza).