# Xamarin App crashing only in Debug mode

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a very basic app I am using to test a 3rd party library binding. I created an IBAction through interface builder. When I click the button that is connected to the IBAction my App crashes. This only happens in Debug mode. The App does not crash in release mode or when ran on my device. The crash happens before any of the IBAction methods are even called.

This is the error that is logged on the console:

```
2014-09-12 08:38:45.293 VinScanSandBox[33818:70b] instance: <CSSNMobileSDKController: 0x7a6a8a30>
mono-rt: Stacktrace:


mono-rt:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>

mono-rt:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x000a6, 0xffffffff>

mono-rt:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:39

mono-rt:   at VinScanSandBox.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00008] in /Users/scordova/Projects/VinScanSandBox/VinScanSandBox/Main.cs:17

mono-rt:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

mono-rt: 
Native stacktrace:


mono-rt: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

update: unchecking "Enable debugging" fixes the crash, but does not explain to me why its happening in the first place. Still searching for full solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you using lisview's in your app then try adding following property of lisview
ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement

in .xaml file for all listview

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your Mono runtime settings are different in debug and release modes. The issue could be for example in its reference counting/GC behavior so the application kills necessary objects in debug mode while you are still trying to execute them. Mono GC represents a weird behavior sometimes, check this for example: [The value of method argument changes after the method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637245/the-value-of-method-argument-changes-after-the-method-is-called/)